# Can someone help me on how to charge this Battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have a *ES* cordless drill and it has a Li-Ion battery (model is *ES GB118L20*).

The original battery charger is missing and there is almost no way for me to get one in my country.

The Battery has 5 *Samsung INR18650-20R* 3.7v cells connected in series.

[image: Inside ES GB118L20 battery]
[image: Inside ES GB118L20 battery]

The battery pins are **BATTERY+**, **BATTERY-** and 4 pins marked **BATTERY1**, **BATTERY2**, **BATTERY3** and **BATTERY4** which are connected between + and - of batteries (probably used for balanced charging). Also there are **T**, **BS** and **ID** pins which I'm not sure of their role.

I tried charging the cells one by one by connecting a *TP4056* charger to each battery pin (for example [**BATTERY-** and **BATTERY1**] or [**BATTERY1** and **BATTERY2**], but was not successful. It didn't even start charging it.

Can anyone help me how to charge this thing?

Comment: it is unclear what is the brand name of the cordless drill ... is it just `ES`? ... is there another name?

Comment: Yes, the brand is ES. It's a Korean brand (probably LG Industrial branch). the website is http://www.es-is.co.kr/html_e/index.html

Comment: And this is the link to the original charger: http://www.es-is.co.kr/bbs/board.php?bo_table=battery_e2&wr_id=8&sca=

Comment: Can you measure any voltages across the individual cells?

Comment: Are those cells as easy to remove as they look? If so, you could easily get a charger from any vape shop. Perhaps not the most convenient option, but it would save you from having to reverse engineer the system.

Comment: Do you need to charge it once, or do you need to make a charger to use it many times, for the whole battery?

Comment: @Finbarr yes. for example between B- and B1, it is 2.65. the same goes for B1 and B2, and the rest.

Comment: @PhilC No. Unfortunately they are welded in and the process of openingthe case is not very easy.

Comment: @AliChen. Yes. I can make a case by CNC, yet the only problem is the charger circuit ATM.

Comment: You should be able to charge cells individually with no problem, unless they are dead dead. Did you try the TP4056 directly to cell terminals?

Comment: @AliChen. No. Ididn't connect them directly to the individual battery cells. This is possible but very impractical, since i need to do this every time. I wanted to see if i can charge them without opening the battery pack. I think the circuits main purpose is to protect it from overcharge or discharge. Maybe i need to connect 5 cell Li-ion charger to charge it, but the price of such charger is so high here that i cant afford it just for a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: connect a constant current supply, with suitable voltage limit (4.25Vx5=21.25V), and leave it until pack voltage is high again. Clearly this will take forever (4+ hours) to charge, and will invalidate any warranty with the pack etc.

Longer answer: while there are many different chargers, there are two ways to charge li-ion cells, either using constant current only, or constant current followed by constant voltage. The quick answer method uses the constant current method where it pushes current into the cells until they are charged. This is the method used in my of the basic battery powered equipment out there, such as vacuum cleaners and some basic drivers. The more complicated method, which is used in the more power sensitive devices, pushes a fixed current into the cells until they reach somewhere around 80-90%, and then a fixed voltage and let the physics of the cells control the current.

In your application, I would suggest that your best bet is to use a desk top power supply, current limit it to something around 0.5Amps, and leave it to charge the pack. This isn't exactly a clean idea, but it works.

Comment: Thanks. Finding a 21v charger is not easy. I probably need to find one with one of those imax b6 chargers and ask him to test it for me. if ok, i would buy one myself.